# Can you lose motherbase staff?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Can you lose special staff members like Hideo Kojima, Ocelot etc. in the motherbase, if your GMP turns red?

Comment: Good, you found the button :). Unfortunately, I don't know the answer...

Comment: I think this might be one of the first times I've seen a user take that advice. Nice one, @Thomas! Very exciting.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the 'special' staff such as Ocelot, Kojima, etc have Direct Contracts. This is indicated by the padlock symbol on the Staff Management screen.

Staff with a Direct Contract will not leave, and additionally cannot be extracted by opposing forces raiding your Forward Operating Bases (FOBs).

Comment: Thanks for alle the comment's and help you guys. You have been a lot of help!

Comment: As someone who just started the game, is there a downside to marking staff members with a Direct Contract?

Comment: @DangerZone The downside is they're not available for deployment missions, and I'm pretty sure you can't pick them when invading/defending a FOB, and they wont be picked to guard your base during a FOB invasion. Because during all these things the staff member has a chance of dying.

Comment: Ah, that's it. Nice one, @GP89! Thanks.